# can I give permission to insert into view, but not to referred table?

Tags: postgresql, schema, permissions, view, table

Here I have a view in public schema referring to the table in private schema:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.products AS 
 SELECT products.id, products.product_id, products.title, products.company_id
   FROM private.products;

ALTER TABLE products
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.products TO postgres;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE products TO viewers;


CREATE OR REPLACE RULE "_INSERT" AS
    ON INSERT TO products DO INSTEAD  INSERT INTO private.products (product_id, title, company_id) 
  VALUES (new.product_id, new.title, new.company_id);
```

the whole thing works fine, 
but I want the client to only be able to operate in **public** schema and not in **private**. Is there a way to setup such permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html)

> Note that the user performing the insert, update or delete on the view
>   must have the corresponding insert, update or delete privilege on the
>   view. In addition the view's owner must have the relevant privileges
>   on the underlying base relations, but the user performing the update
>   does not need any permissions on the underlying base relations.

Comment: I get a "ERROR:  permission denied for sequence <sequance name>" how do I fix that

Comment: GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA private  TO viewers; fixed it